# Forbidden schema names : SYS, DBO (MsSQL)

Tags: sql-server, azure, sql-server-2008, database-design, azure-sql-database

really a silly question, but unable to find an official reference

aside of [sys] and [dbo], what other schema names are not available to sql devps ?

(sure, good practices apply, no DOTS, SPACES and DASHES)

Comment: really??
down-voted for that ??

Comment: Not a silly question.  Just a basic one, and we all had to learn the basics at some point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Schemas that ship with SQL cannot be used. Those can be listed from the `master` database (if no user schemas have been added):

```
SELECT name FROM master.sys.schemas;
```

Results:

```
dbo
guest
INFORMATION_SCHEMA
sys
db_owner
db_accessadmin
db_securityadmin
db_ddladmin
db_backupoperator
db_datareader
db_datawriter
db_denydatareader
db_denydatawriter
```

The best practice is to follow the [rules for regular identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers) in naming schemas, tables, columns, etc. Below is the documentation excerpt:

- The first character must be one of the following:

A letter as defined by the Unicode Standard 3.2. The Unicode definition of letters includes Latin characters from a through z, from A through Z, and also letter characters from other languages.

The underscore (_), at sign (@), or number sign (#).

Certain symbols at the beginning of an identifier have special meaning in SQL Server. A regular identifier that starts with the at sign always denotes a local variable or parameter and cannot be used as the name of any other type of object. An identifier that starts with a number sign denotes a temporary table or procedure. An identifier that starts with double number signs (##) denotes a global temporary object. Although the number sign or double number sign characters can be used to begin the names of other types of objects, we do not recommend this practice. 
Some Transact-SQL functions have names that start with double at signs (@@). To avoid confusion with these functions, you should not use names that start with @@.

- Subsequent characters can include the following: 
  Letters as defined in the Unicode Standard 3.2. 
  Decimal numbers from either Basic Latin or other national scripts. 
  The at sign, dollar sign ($), number sign, or underscore.
- The identifier must not be a Transact-SQL reserved word. SQL Server reserves both the uppercase and lowercase versions of reserved words. When identifiers are used in Transact-SQL statements, the identifiers that do not comply with these rules must be delimited by double quotation marks or brackets. The words that are reserved depend on the database compatibility level. This level can be set by using the ALTER DATABASE statement.
- Embedded spaces or special characters are not allowed.
- Supplementary characters are not allowed.